# Including multiple models to view or controller from different controllers

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, development

I am  developing a "Customer Dashboard" component in Joomla 3.2.
I need to include multiple models of different other components that I have built. I tried to include setModel as per views in controller, here is my businessservices controller

```
class BusinessServicesControllerBusinessServices extends JControllerForm
{
        public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false)
        {

            // set default view if not set
            $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
            $input->set('view', $input->getCmd('view', 'BusinessServices'));
            $viewName       = $this->input->get('view');
            switch ($viewName)
            {
                case 'businessservices':
                    $viewLayout = $this->input->get('layout', 'default');
                    $view = $this->getView($viewName, $format, '', array('base_path' => $this->basePath, 'layout' => $viewLayout));
                    $view->setModel($this->getModel('businessservices'));
                    break;
                case 'trademark':
                    $viewLayout = $this->input->get('layout', 'default');
                    $view = $this->getView($viewName, $format, '', array('base_path' => $this->basePath, 'layout' => $viewLayout));
                    $view->setModel($this->getModel('trademark'));
                    break;
            }
            // call parent behavior
            parent::display($cachable);
        }
}
```

also, I tried to include using:

```
 JLoader::import('joomla.application.component.model');
    JLoader::import( 'llp','components' . DS . 'com_llp_service' . DS . 'models' );
    JLoader::import( 'opc','components' . DS . 'com_opc_services' . DS . 'models' );
```

and getting the model using getInstance method

```
$actionsModel = JModel::getInstance('trademark', 'BusinessServicesModel');
```

it is giving some fatal error, that JModel::getInstance you can not use,

so I want know some proper way to doing this task, including all features to the customer dashboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try JModelLegacy:

```
$actionsModel = JModelLegacy::getInstance('trademark', 'BusinessServicesModel');
```

Maybe you have to include the model file if it is not found:

```
require_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_llp_service/models/trademark.php';
```

Please note: The DS constant is not available in newer Joomla versions.

Comment: yes, JModelLegegacy::getInstance('trademark', 'BusinessServicesModel');  worked fine, but model file was not including using JLoder::import method, i came with your solution to add it manually using require_oince.
Thanks a for the answer!

Comment: PHP itself, though, has a specific DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant that can be used instead of DS. Much longer, of course.